# How to add class if the validation pass in angular

Tags: angular

I am very new to Angular and trying to learn. I am stuck here in form_validation. I am able to add a class when there is an error in that field but I am not getting if suppose there is no error then I need to add another class. This is what I have wrote

```
<input type="text" 
[class.is-invalid]="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched) && name.errors.minlength" minlength="5" 
required 
name="name" 
#name="ngModel" 
[(ngModel)]="account.name" 
placeholder="Enter your Account name" 
class="form-control">
```

in the above code, i am able to add `is-invalid` class but in the else condition, I also want to add `is-valid` class. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple `[class.<css-class>]` directives on a component, e.g.:

```
<div
[class.is-invalid]="..."
[class.is-valid]="..."
>
...
</div>
```

An alternative is using the [ngClass] directive:

```
<div
[ngClass]="condition ? 'is-invalid' : 'is-valid'"
>
...
</div>
```

Comment: I have used like this `[ngClass]="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched) && name.errors.minlength ? 'is-invalid' : 'is-valid'"` But the problem is by default is-valid class is added. Any solution for that ?

Comment: If `name.invalid` is false - which it is before the user changes the field - `is-valid` will be used. So your condition has 3 outcomes: untouched, valid, invalid. Note that you can also bind a method to `[ngClass]`: `[ngClass]=getClass()`. In `getClass` in your component you can then implement a more complex method that returns values for all 3 cases. Cheers